# Having difficulty deciding limits of integration for a joint to marginal pdf

Tags: self-study, density-function, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

A joint pdf, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=5$, is given with the following intervals:

$-1<x<1$

$x^2<y<x^2+{1\over{10}}$

I am trying to find the marginal pdf of $f_Y(y)$ but I am stuck.

[image]

Comment: Have you plotted the area where the joint density is positive?

Comment: I did.it is the area between two quadratic curves. y=x^2 and y=x^2+0.1 and -1<x<+1.  Would it be y^1/2 and (y-0.1)^(1/2). This is my best answer so far, but I feel like I am not scanning all of the area with this.

Comment: From that figure you'll see that for some values of $y$ there are either 0, 1, or 2 sections of $x$ to integrate over.  (Or you can simplify that a bit by noting the symmetry.)

Comment: That is the problem.  How many regions are there? Please!

Answer (score 3):

The joint density can be expressed as $5$ times indicator functions:

> $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 5\times\mathbb{I}_{-1<x<1}\times\mathbb{I}_{x^2<y<x^2+1/10}$$

The marginal density of $Y$, $f_Y(y)$, is therefore the integral of the joint $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ in $x$ over the conditional integration domain:

> $$\{x; -1<x<1,\ y-1/10<x^2<y\}$$

which can also be expressed as

> $$\{x; \max(-1,-\sqrt{y})<x<-\sqrt{\max(0,y-1/10)}\}\cup\{x; \min(1,\sqrt{y})>x>\sqrt{\max(0,y-1/10)}\}$$

with the marginal support of $Y$ obtained by the extreme values of its conditional domain:

> $$y>\min_{-1<x<1}x^2=0\quad\text{ and }\quad y<\max_{-1<x<1}x^2+1/10=11/10$$

meaning that$$f_Y(y)=\int_{\{x;\ f_{X,Y}(x,y)>0\}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\text{d}x$$is given by [using the fact that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X,Y}(-x,y)$ is symmetric]

> $$f_Y(y)=2\int_{\max(0,y-1/10)^{1/2}}^{\min(1,\sqrt{y})} 5\,\text{d}x$$

Answer (score 1):

Each particular value of $y$ corresponds to a horizontal line.

If $0.1 < y < 1,$ then as you go from left to right, that line passes through the red curve, then the blue curve, then the blue curve again, then the red curve again, so you get
$$
f_Y(y) = \int_{-\sqrt y}^{-\sqrt{y-0.1}} 5 \, dx + \int_{\sqrt{y-0.1}}^{\sqrt y} 5 \, dx \quad \text{if } 0.1<y<1.
$$

If $0\le y \le 0.1$ then the horizontal line passes through the red curve twice, so you get
$$
f_Y(y) = \int_{-\sqrt y}^{+\sqrt y} 5\, dx \quad \text{if } 0\le y\le 0.1.
$$

If $1\le y\le 1.1$ then the horizontal line passes through the blue curve twice, so you get
$$
f_Y(y) = \int_{-1}^{-\sqrt{y-0.1}} 5\,dx + \int_{\sqrt{y - 0.1}}^1 5\, dx \quad \text{if } 1\le y\le1.1.
$$

Comment: Typo: the lower bound of the first integral on the last line is -1 and not 0.